# Angular SVG Unit tests how get SVGLengthList

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, svg

Hello I have a question about SVG. I write unit test and i must add to method object with type `SVGLengthList`. I read [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLengthList) and i don't know how can get this object. I try do operation about DOM, where have a 3 `svg` elements, but I can only get object type equal `SVGLength`

```
var $document = $injector.get("$document");
svgParent = $document.find('svg')[0];
svgLength = $document[1].createSVGLength();
```

and my DOM:

```
        var virtualDOM = [
        '<html>',
            '<body>',
                '<svg>',
                    ic_dialog_info,
                    ic_edit,
                '</svg>',
                ic_down,
            '</body>',
        '</html>'
    ].join("");
```

where ic_dialog_info, ic_edit, ic_down it's a svg icon.

Comment: Add something that has a lengthlist e.g. a text element and then get its x member value (which will be an SVGLengthList)

Comment: Th real question is "why do you think you want a SVGLengthList?" what are you planning to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution how create SVGLengthList, I created element tspan with Namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg". next I use  property 'x' where 'x' is SVGAnimatedLengthList, and I take baseVal) that's all :) very simple :)

```
svgLengthList = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'tspan').x.baseVal;
```